# Simplifying complex functions and expressions with real results

Tags: complex-numbers

So I integrated a real function

$$ \int_{0}^{k_{max}}\frac{k^4}{(k^2 + x)^2 + y^2} $$
$$= k_{max} + \frac{1}{2y} \left(i (x + iy)^{3/2} \arctan{\left(\frac{k_{max}}{(\sqrt{(x + i y})}\right)} - i (x - iy)^{3/2} \arctan{\left(\frac{k_{max}}{(\sqrt{(x - i y})}\right)}\right) \;.
$$

All variables are real numbers ($x,y,k_{max}\in  R$, and actually $k_{max},y>0$).

I know that the imaginary part in the result is 0 (complex + complex conjugated expression and from testing values). But now the question:

**Is there any way or "tricks" to simplify such an expression if only the real part of the result is needed?**

I tried rewriting a lot and either the expressions get very lengthy or don't go anywhere (rewriting atan as log and so on...). I'm wondering if I am missing something more obvious.

Thanks in advance for any help.